# Reading an ASCII File in Fortran

Tags: file, fortran, ascii

I have a question. I have an ASCII FILE full of numbers on my desktop but I need to know how to read the ASCII FILE using FORTRAN. Can you show me an example of how its done or what command that is?

Comment: Well, you have to be a little more specific on how your data looks like and what you want to achieve. Reading a bunch of numbers from an ascii file can be as simple as: 'open(unit=fu, filename="data.txt"); read(fu,*) a; close(fu)', where 'a' is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't give many details, so I'm going to make some assumptions here. Let's say that your file consists of 3 columns of floating point numbers, i.e.

```
1.2345 -4.222e7 2.229
77.222 77e7     50
...
```

If you simply want to read these numbers without storing them in an array, this could be done straightforwardly as

```
    integer :: unit
    real    :: a,b,c
    unit = 20
    open(unit,"foo.txt",status="old",action="read")
    do
        read(unit,*,end=1) a, b, c
        write(*,*) "I got", a, b, c
    end do
    1 close(unit)
```

If you want to store these numbers as an array, however, you first need to allocate the appropriate amount of space, for which you need to know the number of lines. This requires a preliminary pass through the file, sadly, because Fortran doesn't provide growing arrays, and implementing a replacement yourself is inconvenient. Assuming you use fortran 90 or newer, this would look something like this:

```
    integer :: unit, i, n
    real, allocatable :: data(:,:)
    unit = 20
    open(unit,"foo.txt",status="old",action="read")
    n = 0
    do
        read(unit,*,end=1)
        n = n+1
    end do
    1 rewind(unit)
    allocate(data(n,3))
    do i = 1, n
        read(unit,*) data(i,:)
    end do
    close(unit)
```

The unit number is simply some unique user-chosen number. Beware that some low numbers have predefined meanings. It is common to define a function like getlun() that will provide a free unit number for you. A quick google search produced this: http://ftp.cac.psu.edu/pub/ger/fortran/hdk/getlun.f90. If you have a new enough compiler, you can use open(newunit=unit,...) which will automatically assign a free unit number to the variable "unit".